# Find and remove all parenthesis data in VIM

Tags: regex, vim

I have a csv files in VIM that looks like this:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc (Friday, 23/06/17)
ddd,eee,fff (Saturday, 24/06/17)
ggg,hhh,iii (Sunday, 25/06/17)
```

I would like to delete all parenthesis & its content to look like this:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc
ddd,eee,fff
ggg,hhh,iii
```

I have tried doing this but it's only deleting the parenthesis

```
:%s/(*)//g
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it, you're missing the `.`:

```
:%s/(.*)//g
```

The dot matches all the characters, so using `.*` means find all strings of characters of any length

**Edit:**

As [sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) stated, `g` if for matching all occurrences in the same line and `.*` will greedily match from the first `(` to the last `)` in the line, so there won't be another to match in the same line, so it can be removed. You can match only simple pairs of braces with `([^(]*)` which means find any string of characters that don't include `(` that is surrounded by `()`. So the modified suggestion is to use:

```
:%s/([^(]*)//g
```

Comment: or just `:%s/(.*)` as `g` flag is ineffective in this regex

Comment: Why is `g` ineffective?

Comment: it will change `1 3(foo) and (bar)` to `1 3` irrespective of g flag... in such cases, use `:%s/([^)]*)//g`

Comment: I didn't want to complicate the answer, that is why I only wrote the dot. But what is the reason that `g` is ineffective?

Comment: because [.* is greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/429/greedy-and-lazy-quantifiers#t=201707041159029509718)... `s/(.*)//` means delete from first `(` in the line to last `)` in the line.. so `g` is redundant... I get that OP used `g`, your answer is fine... I just wanted to add additional info I felt would be helpful to add to the answer

Comment: I thought `g` was for replace in all file, reading the documentation again I see it is for multiple occurrences in the same line. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`:%s/(.*)//g` or `da(` from inside the `()` for each line if you intend to delete few leaving others.

Comment: or `:%norm f(da)`... the `g` flag is not needed with greedy regex.. it will change `1 3(foo) and (bar)` to `1 3` irrespective of `g` flag... in such cases, use `:%s/([^)]*)//g`